# How to fix to persist data relating 2 tables to database using JavaEE, servlet, jsp,EJB, JSTL

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, ejb, jstl

I have written code to add products but I am not able to persist data to db tables.To insert data I need to think about product table and category table. 
category table have  id and name field. The product table is where i need to insert data such as name, price, description and category_id which is referenced from the id of category table.

I think the point of problem is the category field. It need to be set with **product.setCategory(category);**
since it is not letting me set with SetcategoryID .

So, I am seeking help where i have mistaken or how should i correct the following codes in adminservlet. I have included codes that affects this thing.

**Update:** Solved it after staying whole night trying different things. Your suggestions and knowledge are still welcomed since Your code may be more efficient than mine since I am beginner to Java platform. One thing still need to be solved it is to redirect or forward response after data inserting succeed
Its not working.

**AdminServlet**

```
else if (userPath.equals("/admin/addProduct")){


            String name = request.getParameter("name");
            Double price = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("price")) ;

            String description = request.getParameter("description");
            //Integer category_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("category_id")) ;
            Integer category_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("category_id")) ;

            //Category category = new Category(request.getParameter("category"););
            //String category = category(request.getParameter("category"));
                boolean validationErrorFlag;
                validationErrorFlag = validator.validateForm(name, request);
                // if validation error found, return  to same
                if (validationErrorFlag == true) {
                    request.setAttribute("validationErrorFlag", validationErrorFlag);

                }
                else {
                    try{
                    request.setAttribute("name" , name);
                    request.setAttribute("price" , price);
                    request.setAttribute("description" , description);
                    // get selected category
                    //Category category = categoryFacade.find(Integer.parseInt(categoryId));
                    request.setAttribute("category" , category_id);

                    productManager.addProduct(name, price, description, category);
                    response.sendRedirect("/admin/showProduct");
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex){
                        ex.toString();
                    }
                }    

        }
```

**ProductManager.java**

```
public Product addProduct(String name, Double price, String description, Category category) {

        Product product = new Product();
        product.setName(name);
        //product.setCatId();
        product.setCategory(category);
        product.setPrice(price);
        product.setDescription(description);

        em.persist(product); 
        return product;
    }
```

**addProduct.jsp**

```
<h1>Add Product item: </h1>


                <form id ="addProductForm" action="<c:url value='/admin/addProduct'/>" method="post">
                    <c:if test="${!empty validationErrorFlag}">

                        <p><fmt:message key="validationErrorMessage"/> </p>
                        <c:if test="${!empty nameError}"><p><fmt:message key="nameError"/></p></c:if>
                        <c:if test="${!empty categoryError}"><p><fmt:message key="categoryError"/></p></c:if>
                        <c:if test="${!empty priceError}"><p><fmt:message key="priceError"/></p></c:if>
                        <c:if test="${!empty descriptionError}"><p><fmt:message key="descriptionError"/></p></c:if>


                    </c:if>

                    <p><strong>Product Name:</strong></p>
                    <input class ="form-control" type="text" name="name" value="${param.name}">
           <p><strong>Product Category:</strong></p>
            <select id="category" name="category" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
            <c:forEach var="category" items="${categories}" varStatus="iter">
                <option value="${category.id}">${category.name}</option>
            </c:forEach>
            </select>
                    <p><strong>Product Price:</strong></p>
                    <input class ="form-control col-md-6" type="text" name="price">
                    <p><strong>Product details:</strong></p>
                    <textarea class ="form-control" type="textarea" name="description" rows="4">   
                    </textarea>
                    <br>
                    <p><input class ="btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
                </form>
```

**category.java entity**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "category")
    private Collection<Product> productCollection;
```

**Product.java entity**

```
 @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Category category;
    /*
    @OneToOne
    private Category categoryId;
    */
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "product")
    private Collection<OrderedProduct> orderedProductCollection;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my self. here is solution if someone need in future.

```
public Product addProduct(String name, Double price, String description, Integer category_id) {
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setName(name);
        //product.setCatId();
        Category category = new Category(category_id);
        product.setCategory(category);
        product.setPrice(price);
        product.setDescription(description);

        //em.persist(category);
        em.persist(product); 
        return product;
    }
```